# After upgrading to 12.04, installing Rhythmbox and uninstalling Banshee music lens doesn't open any audio

Tags: unity, 12.04, upgrade, rhythmbox, lenses

I can search in music, but when i click at any icon in music lens or in music scope for home lens, it does nothing and don't disappears. But i still can open music files from files lens or from Nautilus.

How to solve this problem? Isn't it a bug?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried removing and reinstalling the music lens?

Comment: @aking1012 yes. i've found interesting thing: songs start to play when clicking on one in music lens, but albums don't.

Comment: try creating playlists of the albums and searching for those instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug report for the album issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-lens-music/+bug/970509

Apparently it has been fixed in -proposed.